# Problem with understanding natural number difference

Tags: elementary-number-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

[Proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Construction_of_Inverse_Completion/Natural_Number_Difference) says the following about difference in natural numbers:

> In the context of the natural numbers, the difference is defined as:
>
> $n−m=p⟺m+p=n$
>
> from which it can be seen that the above congruence can be understood
>   as:
>
> $(x_1,y_1)⊠(x_2,y_2)⟺x_1+y_2=x_2+y_1⟺x_1−y_1=x_2−y_2$
>
> Thus this congruence defines an equivalence between pairs of elements
>   which have the same difference.

What does that all mean? I don't understand it at all. Why did they call $n−m=p⟺m+p=n$ a congruence? How does it imply that $(x_1,y_1)(x_2,y_2)⟺x_1+y_2=x_2+y_1⟺x_1−y_1=x_2−y_2$?

[Here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Cross-Relation) is the definition of $⊠$.